# What are the effective open-source methods for storing and managing encryption keys in a language-agnostic manner when an HSM is unavailable?

Tags: encryption, key-management, hsm

When HSMs are not accessible, we often need alternative methods for securely storing and managing encryption keys

What open-source options exist for effectively managing encryption keys in a language-agnostic manner when HSMs are unavailable?